# Popup window with different contents

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup, window

I have some buttons containing different contents and when the user clicks, a new window should popup with the content for the clicked button.

There should only be one popup window where the content should be altered, depending on which button the user has pressed.

I'm using PHP to generate HTML code but I can't find a way to do it as PHP is server side..
Don't want to use href in html, JS could work, although I'm not great at JS..

Comment: you have to do it with javascript, just reference always the same window

Comment: Why don;t you want to use an href? Seems like the logical way to go.

Comment: @epascarello, href(html and PHP) will not let me alter the content, I want to get the content from a DB and display it in the popup window.

Comment: @aleation Could you explain how I should do it? :P I'm a real beginner at JS..

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a site](http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php) that will auto-generate javascript code for a popup window that you can attach to your buttons

Comment: Have seen your link although the generated button will not be able to pass different content to the popup window, or will it?

Comment: If you are passing content to the popup, you are probably doing it wrong. Create a page for the various content types and pass the popup the URL of the relevant page from each button.